# Free Host perform better then paid host or something else is wrong with my website?

Tags: php, web-services, hosting

Nobody can not solve this problem on other forums but this forum is professional and I am hope that some expert can help me to find right solution for this problem.
 I will be very grateful for you!

**Problem:**
Ok, I have free hosting with 000webhost where I have website here : https://macanovic.000webhostapp.com/upload/

and

I have paid hosting  and its the same website (php script) but with domain name: **translatesubtitles.com**

and if you test my website , upload SRT subtitle file and translate it and click on DOWNLOAD button , in how many seconds file started downloading? from the 000webhost and from Paid host ? My start in 5 seconds with 000webhost and from Paid Host it takes 60 seconds to download start , what can be the problem? the free webhost is better then paid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with free or paid hosting. It depends on Which type of server or network your paid hosting provider is using. It can also be the location or network issue. Even firewall rules. So there are too many if's and but's.
trying a tracert to both servers to know some more details.